# SDK and AVD issues when trying o create Samsung galaxy tab emulator

Tags: android, sdk, android-emulator, android-virtual-device

I try to create a galaxy tab emulator following all the tuts on the net, but I cant find Available packages => Third Party Add-ons => Samsung Electronics add-ons in my SDK manager !!!

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Read This.](http://developer.samsung.com/android/tools-sdks/Samsung-GALAXY-Tab-Emulator)

From that page, download the file `addon_galaxy_tab_samsung_electronics_8.zip`.

Copy the folder `addon_galaxy_tab_samsung_electronics_8` to `~/sdk/add-ons`.

Then open AVD manager, Make a new Emulator,and in the target choose `GALAXY TAB Addon`.

If you meant Galaxy Tab 10.1, use these settings too:

> Device: 10.1" WXGA (Tablet) (1280x800)
>  
>   Target: Galaxy Tab Addon *(from what you downloaded).*
>   RAM:1024 *(don't do this if you have a slow PC; it's not really necessary).*
>   VM Heap: 32

Comment: Ensure Android 2.2 (API8) is installed in your SDK Manager or the Galaxy Tab Addon won't be visible in the Target dropdown box in the AVD manager.